# how to play full m3u audio stream in ios

Tags: ios, m3u

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yyyyy.com/radio.m3u"];
  moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

   // Register to receive a notification when the movie has finished playing.
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:moviePlayer];
   NSLog(@"start");
   if ([moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)]) {


       NSLog(@"IF");
       // Use the new 3.2 style API
       moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
       moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
       [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
       [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
   } else {
       // Use the old 2.0 style API
      // moviePlayer.movie = MPMovieControlModeHidden;
       NSLog(@"else");
       [moviePlayer play];  
   }
```

In the above code is used in ios development,but m3u to play only 20 seconds how to play full m3u in unstoppable please give some tutorials.

Comment: [m3u is an audio *playlist* file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U) which ends up being a plain text file.  It is not the actual audio stream.